# Outline overview for available datasets in QGIS

Tags: qgis, data-collection, outline

Assuming you have several 100 000 files on your discs

- which are all georeferenced
- which are all readable within QGIS (Raster maps, sqlite maps, vector maps, shapefile etc.)

After 20+ years in working with geodata I lost the overview over my collection.

In consumer tools like Oziexplorer or Oruxmaps you have a feature where you can see the outline of available datasets at your region of interest. If you click on this outline, the data is loaded.

Is there a tool like this in QGIS, maybe a plugin, and able to handle 100 000++ of datasets?

Comment: The first step could be to index the vector layers with http://www.gdal.org/ogrtindex.html.

Comment: Just tried ogrtindex and gdaltindex! Worked with with BIL and TIF, failed with OziExplorer files and shp, due to many different projections. Doesn't allow autoload on dblclick in QGIS. Probably a good starting point, if someone likes to write a python plugin for QGIS.

Comment: Different projections should not make problem if you have a new enough GDAL version. Read (obviously copy-pasted text) about -t_srs parameter in http://www.gdal.org/ogrtindex.html and http://www.gdal.org/gdaltindex.html. You are right that for QGIS those tools offer only a starting point.

Comment: Just found out that this commandline tool is already included in QGIS as a GUI. The following link is in German only: http://de.digital-geography.com/ubersicht-uber-rasterkarten-erstellen-mit-qgis-und-gdal/ But still the problem, with projections and no automatic loading.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that. The same in English http://www.digital-geography.com/create-raster-layer-index-qgis-gdal/. Seems not to be very new thing but I guess that it has been as a separate plugin https://trac.osgeo.org/qgis/ticket/1563. You may consider to make a QGIS feature request/suggestion about adding the support for mixed coordinate systems.

Comment: Yes and No: The VRT solution will kill you if you load 100 000 ++ indexed files. Actually it already kills productive working with 50 AsterGDEM BIL files. What would be the solution is a simple python script, which uses the "identify feature" results and just loads the "location" property ... I can't be the first coming up with this idea?

Comment: Gdaltindex is not a VRT solution. Gdalbuildvrt is a VRT solution. Any solution that loads 100000 indexed files will lead to death and therefore gdaltindex (+shapefiles or some database backend) that supports spatial indexing is what MapServer is using. Because MapServer is a server software it opens the files automatically and therefore it needs to be used with reasonable scale limits. Scale limits can be used on desktop as well. Your idea about clicking the vector feature for opening the corresponding raster is simple but I have not seen it implemented in desktop GIS.

Comment: My VRT comment was an answer to your link: trac.osgeo.org/qgis/ticket/1563